# How to run an swift app in background?

Tags: json, swift, web-services, service

I'm in need to run an swift app in background for sometime (say 5 sec) Even when app close and when run service call webservice and get data

Comment: Check [this article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started), it's about "NSURLSession" and how to enable background transfers.

Comment: when app close not work  
but how I can still receive messages on whatsapp for example, even if I kill it?